# Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 3.1.4. Add-Migration not work

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I want to use migrations in my EF Core Lib Project.

I installed NuGet packages

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.4
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 3.1.4
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 3.1.4

But the `Add-Migration` command never appeared in the PM console.

When I restarted Visual Studio 2019. There was an error in the PM console:

```
Package Manager Console Host Version 5.5.0.6473

Type 'get-help NuGet' to see all available NuGet commands.

& : The term 'C:\Users\ruslan.runchev\.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools\3.1.4\tools\init.ps1' is not recognized as the n
ame of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the pa
th is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:45
+ ... rgs+=$_}; & 'C:\Users\ruslan.runchev\.nuget\packages\microsoft.entity ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\ruslan...\tools\init.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

PM>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you use visual studio? Either way try `dotnet ef migrations add name_of_migration`

Comment: did you do `dotnet ef migrations add`?

Comment: Also try rempve the `Tools` package

Comment: I use VS 2019 16.5.4. Is "dotnet ef migrations add" a command of Package Manager console?

Comment: I removed the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools package and even installed an earlier version. Did not help

Comment: @r00xus it is command on any console)

Comment: I also tried to clear the NuGet cache despite the fact that this is a completely new project